# How to dynamically create SWT buttons and their actions?

Tags: java, swt

I have one OK button(push button) created.

Based on user input i want to dynamically create 1 to 10 SWT buttons(check box).

How to create it?

If OK button is clicked, how to display which are all check box button has been selected?

Please find below snippet I am trying with:

```
Set<String> Groups = getData(Contents);
for(String group : contentGroups) {

contentButton = new Button(fComposite, SWT.CHECK);  

    // is this right way to create dynamic buttons?

    contentButton.setText(group);

}

okButton = new Button(lowComposite, SWT.PUSH);

okButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){

        //Here how to get the selection status of contentButtons?       
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to save the `Button`s in a `final` or `static` `List` to be able to access them / iterate over them in the `Listener`

Comment: But how to save and iterate? how to get variable name of all contentButtons?ok button and check boxes are created in different composites. Please give some snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will print out the selection state of the buttons:

```
Set<String> Groups = getData(Contents);

final List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

for(String group : contentGroups)
{
    Button newButton = new Button(fComposite, SWT.CHECK);  
    newButton.setText(group);

    // save the button
    buttons.add(newButton);
}

Button okButton = new Button(lowComposite, SWT.PUSH);

okButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        // iterate over saved buttons
        for(Button button : buttons)
        {
            System.out.println(button.getText() + ": " + button.getSelection());
        }       
    }
}
```